# Shared contextmenu only working after original controls CM has been opened

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I wrote a contextmenu in XAML-code for a specific control, which opens after right-clicking the control and I would like to have a second control having the same contextmenu.

```
   <ListBox.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
                 <MenuItem Header="Command01" Command="{Binding ContextMenuCommand01}"/>
                 <MenuItem Header="Command02" Command="{Binding ContextMenuCommand02}"/>
                 <Separator/>
                 <MenuItem Header="Option01" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Option01Selected}" />
                 <MenuItem Header="Option02" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Option02Selected}" />
          </ContextMenu>
   </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

What I have done is setting the contextmenu of the second control to the first ones in code behind and open it manually when the right mousebutton is clicked.

```
   this.SecondControl.ContextMenu = this.FirstControl.ContextMenu;
```

Now the second control behaves in a way I do not understand: The context menu of the second opens correctly, but none of the commands gets fired when clicked and none of the properties updated.
But... if I previously open the first controls menu, which behaves like expected, then the second context menu also behaves correctly.

How can this be explained?